# Problema al insertar valor null en un Timestamp on Update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Cuando cree la tabla tb_usuario, puse un campo para que obtenga la fecha y hora exacta al momento de hacer un registro a la tabla tb_usuario, pero cuando hago un insert, no coje ni se muestra la fecha y hora en la que se inserto algo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el codigo que utilizo para el insert:

```
INSERT INTO tb_usuario values (null ,'alias','apellido','nombre','12','tipo doc','nro doc', 'correo','nro cel','puesto','area puesto', null ,'ip','nombre pc')
```

y este es mi tabla tb_usuario:

```
drop table if exists tb_usuario;
create table tb_usuario
    (
cod_usuario INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
alias_usuario VARCHAR (15),
apellidos VARCHAR(50),
nombres VARCHAR(50),
edad INT,
tipo_doc VARCHAR (50),
nro_doc VARCHAR(15),
correo VARCHAR (50),
nro_cel VARCHAR (9),
puesto VARCHAR (50),
area_puesto VARCHAR(50),
fecha_creacion_usuario TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
ip_v4 VARCHAR(20),
nombre_pc VARCHAR(30),
PRIMARY KEY(cod_usuario)
);
```

el motor de bd es mysql workbench. 
Que estoy haciendo mal? alguna recomendación?

Comment: Al menos en MySQL 5.6 tu creación e insert parecieran funcionar correctamente, revisa este fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e35f024/1. Tienes algún trigger en este tabla que esté nuleando la columna?

Answer (score 2):

Lo que sucede es que estas declarando que cuando se haga un **UPDATE** se planche el momento de tiempo en que se hizo, debes de cambiarlo para que lo haga en el **INSERT** de la siguiente forma:

```
fecha_creacion_usuario TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Y si quieres que dicho campo registre tanto en el **INSERT** como en el **UPDATE** seria así:

```
fecha_creacion_usuario TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: eh dropeado la tabla y lo volvi a crear con ese tipo de dato y sigue saliendome null

Comment: probe con su comentario anterior pero sigo sin obtener resultados. [![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26QUm.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26QUm.jpg) a que se debe? PD.- EL CODIGO QUE utilizo para hacer el insert es el siguiente: INSERT INTO tb_usuario values (null ,'alias','apellido','nombre','12','tipo doc','nro doc', 'correo','nro cel','puesto','area puesto', null ,'ip','nombre pc')

Comment: Lo que has puesto como respuesta deberia de ir en tu pregunta por favor edita tu pregunta y añade lo que pusiste como respuesta y quita esa respuesta, ahora me he percatado de que en tu INSERT le estas enviando al parametro que corresponde para fecha, le estas enviando NULL, por eso te inserta null, cuando son campos calculados no es necesario que los envies en el INSERT. @Kevinramirezsoto

Comment: @Kevinramirezsoto al escribir tu consulta así: `INSERT INTO tb_usuario values (null ,'alias','apellido','nombre','12','tipo doc','nro doc', 'correo','nro cel','puesto','area puesto', null ,'ip','nombre pc')` estás incurriendo en una mala práctica. Por comodidad muchos programadores omiten en los insert los nombres de las columnas y ese es el problema, porque luego le pasas `null` al campo en cuestión. Si haces lo que se te dice en esta respuesta y escribes el insert poniendo los nombres de columnas, omitiendo esta que obtiene su valor por defecto, no tendrás `null` en el campo.

Answer (score 0):

Como su nombre indica, `ON UPDATE` funciona al hacer un update, lo cual no tiene nada que ver con un `INSERT`.

Si quieres que te asigne un valor automáticamente al hacer un `INSERT`, AND la cláusula es `DEFAULT`

```
fecha_creacion_usuario TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html